# Is there any better way to implement the try..catch mechanism?

Tags: c++, linked-list, try-catch

**LinkedList.h**

```
#pragma once

class LinkedList {
    int size = 1;
    struct Node {
        int ivar = 0;
        Node* next = nullptr;
    };
    Node* rootNode = new Node();
    Node* createNode(int ivar);
    auto getSize() const { return size; }
public:
    LinkedList() = delete;
    LinkedList(int val) {
        rootNode->ivar = val;
    }
    const bool addNode(int val, int pos);
    const bool delNode(int pos);
    ~LinkedList() = default;
};
```

---

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
#include <exception>
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::createNode(int ivar) {
    try {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->ivar = ivar;
        return newNode;
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) {
        return nullptr;
    }
}

const bool LinkedList::addNode(int val, int pos = -1) {
    pos = (pos >= size) || (pos < 0) ? getSize() - 1 : pos;
    Node* newNode = createNode(val);
    if (newNode == nullptr) {
        return false;
    }
    Node* temp_ptr = rootNode;
    for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
        temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
    }
    temp_ptr->next = newNode;
    size++;
    return true;
}

const bool LinkedList::delNode(int pos) {
    pos = (pos >= size) || (pos < 0) ? getSize() - 1 : pos;
    try {
        auto temp_ptr = rootNode;
        if (pos == 0) {
            rootNode = rootNode->next;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
                temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
            }
        }
        temp_ptr->next = temp_ptr->next->next;
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) {
        return false;
    }
    size--;
    return true;
}
```

---

This is a code for linked list assignment. Is there any better way to implement the try-catch mechanism?

Comment: `catch (const std::exception&) {
        return nullptr;
    }` if you are going to do that, remove the exceptions altogether. You are ignoring the exceptions and just returning false no matter what the error

Comment: Which part of `delNode` do you believe could throw an exception?

Comment: On an unrelated note, that the only way you can make an empty list is to create a one-element list and delete its only element is a needless complication.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 You need to first ask yourself “could any of this throw?”  If there’s no risk of an exception, there is no need to write any code to handle it.

Comment: In `createNode()` you don't need the `try`/`catch` at all.   The only exception will be thrown by the `new` expression.    Simply `#include <new>` and then create the node as `Node* newNode = new (std::nothrow) Node();`.   The `try`/`catch` in `delNode()` is not needed, since nothing in the `try` block will throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What C++ exceptions are not

Exceptions are not an alternative way to implement `if / else`. Exceptions have totally different and much more complicated semantics and they are made solely for error handling. In fact, it is such a topic that until 1994 no one really knew how to write proper exception safe code.

#### What you should do with exceptions

- Print them out / log them etc etc
- Rethrow them, so that whoever calls your method can catch the exception and know what went wrong.

#### What happens if you don't catch an exception

- `std::terminate` is called and your program exits

#### When to use exceptions

- Use exceptions when you can not handle the error locally inside the function. Example:

#### When to use `try / catch`

Use `try / catch` when you *know* that some function or some piece of code can throw an exception.

try {
//code here can throw
this_func_can_throw_in_some_cases();
} catch (exception& e)
{
...
}

```
struct A{
   A() {
    //some error happened here. Now you can't tell anyone about the error.
    //You can't return error code or true/false from the constructor.
    //Use exceptions!
    throw myexception("Something bad happened");
   }
};

//
void somefunc()
{
    try {
       A a; //constructor of A can throw
    } catch (const myexception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;  //
        throw; //rethrow the exception.
    }
}
```

#### Your code

In your code in `createNode` method:

```
LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::createNode(int ivar) {
    try {
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->ivar = ivar;
        return newNode;
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc &ba) {
        std::cout << "Failed to allocate: " << ba.what() << std::endl;
        throw;
    }
}

int main()
{
  try {
     list.createNode(...)
  } catch (const std::bad_alloc& ba)
  {
     //failed...
     //no rethrowing, we are already in main and we can't rethrow stuff from here.
  }
}
```

This is pointless:

```
    try {
        auto temp_ptr = rootNode;
        if (pos == 0) {
            rootNode = rootNode->next;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < pos - 1; i++) {
                temp_ptr = temp_ptr->next;
            }
        }
        temp_ptr->next = temp_ptr->next->next;
    }
    catch (const std::exception&) {
        return false;
    }
```

There's no need for a `try / catch` here because nothing in the `try` block can throw. If nothing can `throw`, then `catch` is just sitting there doing nothing. You can safely remove that.

---

I suggest you read [Exceptions and Error Handling](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#how-exceptions) chapter in isocpp FAQ for a detailed intro to this topic. Specifically learn about

- Learn about exception safety guarantees (weak / strong)
- Where to not use exceptions (for example, in destructors)

Answer (score 2):

If you catch an exception, more so something general like `std::exception` which is typically the base class of all other exceptions, you generally want to log it and rethrow it. Silencing some general exception is a *terrible* idea that defeats the purpose of exceptions. Generally:

- If there is a specific exception that you know exactly how to recover from (something like GUI failed, fall back on text-userinterface), do your backup plan.
- In all other cases, log it (to a log file, log stream etc) rethrow the exception.

In your specific case, you're better off not catching the exception at all since you don't do anything in particular with it.

Also you can see this talk titled ["Declarative Control Flow"](https://youtu.be/WjTrfoiB0MQ) which describes ways to replace `try...catch` to improve code structure.